# Why is this Django form bypassing my custom manager when creating a new object?

Tags: python, django

I have a basic Django ModelForm to create a new user:

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User

    # stuff here

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

I also have a custom UserManager for handling the User creation function, which also creates a UserProfile and attaches it to the User:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

def create_user(self, email, password=None):
    """Create a standard user."""

    email = self.normalize_email(email)
    user = self.model(email=email)
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()
    profile = UserProfile()
    profile.user = user
    profile.save()
    return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
     objects = UserManager()
```

However, whenever the UserCreationForm is called successfully, it creates the User, but doesn't create the UserProfile.

My question is, why is the UserCreationForm bypassing my custom UserManager? Is there some special syntax I need to give the form to tell it my model has a custom manager?

I am also using django.views.generic.CreateView as the view, so I guess I could change the post method manually to create a User and UserProfile, but I'd like to know why this is failing before coming up with some hacky fix considering it seems like a very basic operation.

Thanks

Comment: [because `create_user` is not `save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods)

Comment: Your code is not calling `create_user(...)` anywhere. Probably you wanted to override `create(...)` or `save(...)` method of `User`. Normally `Manager` is not used to create instances of `Model`. The documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method says nothing about `save(...)` method of `ModelForm` calling `Manager` methods.